# Recipient selfie on signature | Docusign Rest API | C#

Tags: docusignapi

C# Rest API
How to a require a recipient selfie on signature?
I'm using Docusign Rest API and C#

I have try ask the support chat about some documentation, but without success.

Comment: you mean you want the recipient to take a picture of their face so that AI can recognize them using face recognition and confirm their identity?

Comment: @InbarGazit, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present time DocuSign doesn't have face recognition technology as part of the [DocuSign Identity Verification](https://www.docusign.com/products/identify) offering. You can use other means of identifying people which typically means they have to scan their government issued IDs.